# Local Storage on page refresh returns empty value

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce, local-storage

Local storage returns an empty string after page refresh on woocomerce not sure why code below returns an empty value when there should be the value stored inside:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keyup(saveSettings);
  if (window.localStorage) {
    loadSettings();
  }
});

function loadSettings() {
  $('#billing_first_name').val(localStorage.bfn);
  $('#billing_last_name').val(localStorage.bln);
  $('#billing_company').val(localStorage.cn);
  $('#billing_phone').val(localStorage.phone);
  $('#billing_email').val(localStorage.ea);
}

function saveSettings() {
  localStorage.bfn = $('#billing_first_name').val();
  localStorage.bln = $('#billing_last_name').val();
  localStorage.cn = $('#billing_company').val();
  localStorage.phone = $('#billing_phone').val();
  localStorage.ea = $('#billing_email').val();

}
```

Anytips are helpful thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `localStorage.setItem(NAME, VALUE)` and `localStorage.getItem(NAME)`

Comment: I think it was also working by setting/getting properties, maybe the implementation changed, not sure becuase I've always use setItem/getItem.

Answer (score 3):

You're using it wrong, this is how you set and retreive items:

```
localStorage.setItem('name', 'value');
var value = localStorage.getItem('name');
console.log(value); //value
```

So in your case, e.g.:

```
localStorage.setItem('bfn', $('#billing_first_name').val()); //Set value
$('#billing_first_name').val(localStorage.getItem('bfn')); //Get value
```